# How to compare a mutez value with int in smartpy

Tags: smartpy, python

When trying to check the transferred value is positive I get an error that `TMutez` is not `TIntOrNat`.:

```
sp.verify(sp.amount > 0, "Amount should be positive")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like SmartPy type inference doesn't auto-cast 0 to mutez. We need to do the following:

```
sp.amount > sp.mutez(0)
```

Comment: It's perfectly exact.